# StateListDrawable not working in OnDraw() method of KeyboardView

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-softkeyboard, android-drawable, statelistdrawable

I am trying to change the keyboard key background dynamically at run time. But state list drawable is not working in onDraw method of KeyboardView class.
My written code is -

```
@Override
public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Key key : keys) {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();


        states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
        states.addState(new int[]{},
                new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));

        states.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
        states.draw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(24);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        if (key.label != null) {
            canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width / 2),
                    key.y + (key.height / 2), paint);
        } else {
            key.icon.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            key.icon.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: where do you change the "state" of `states` Drawable?

Comment: In button background, I don't need to change state. clickMeButton.setBackgroundDrawable(states) is work. In Keyboard view, do I need to change the state of stateListDrawable? How can I change it?

Comment: i see you are creating a new `StateListDrawable` and use it for `Canvas` drawing only, you are not using it in any other place

Comment: Yes, how can i solve this?

Comment: read the `Keyboard.Key` API? use `Keyboard.Key#onPressed()`? or `Keyboard.Key#pressed` ?

Answer (score 2):

I removed StateListDrawable and dynamically change the background with following condition in the onDraw method.

```
if(key.pressed){
    Drawable dr = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
    dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
        dr.draw(canvas);
}else{
    Drawable dr = new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW);
    dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
        dr.draw(canvas);
}
```